# Emulating sigwaitinfo on Mac OS X?

Tags: c, macos, signals, portability

As far as I could tell, [`sigwaitinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigwaitinfo.html) is not available on [Mac OS X](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/sigwaitinfo.html).
Is there any other, possibly OS X specific, function that could be used to emulate this function behavior?

I.e. wait until a signal is sent *and* then being able to access a `siginfo_t` structure describing the sent signal.

Comment: The POSIX specification for `sigwaitinfo()` references `sigwait()` ('_The sigwaitinfo() function shall be equivalent to the sigwait() function if the info argument is NULL. If the info argument is non-NULL, the sigwaitinfo() function shall be equivalent to sigwait(), except that the selected signal number shall be stored in the si_signo member, and the cause of the signal shall be stored in the si_code member_'), and `sigwait()` is provided on Mac OS X.  That may make it possible to almost emulate `sigwaitinfo()`, but it will certainly be decidedly non-trivial.

Comment: As @JonathanLeffler mentioned, it's definitely non-trivial to emulate `sigwaitinfo(2)`. One possible workaround is to set up your signal handlers with the `SA_SIGINFO` flag. This allows you to set up a handler that receives a `siginfo_t *` as its second argument. From there you could extract and copy the relevant information to a global variable and later access it. But of course, it's not thread safe and it forces you to refactor the signal handlers code (and the code that sets them up).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, for now I decided to go with a stub implementation only filling si_signo.